# what is the fastest, MPI-supported, genetic algorithm c++ library

Tags: java, c++, mpi, genetic-algorithm

I want to use genetic algorithm to solve my feature selection + structure learning problem. Since we have huge amount of data with very large searching space, plus we need to do a lot of simulations, so speed is very important. I found several libraries as in

[What is the most active genetic programming library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2549512/what-is-the-most-active-genetic-programming-library)
[Which Java library/libraries for Genetic Algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300423/which-java-library-libraries-for-genetic-algorithms)

But which one is the fastest one?

Here are some features I want (sorted by priority):
0) free for academic
1) fast
2) support MPI (we have MVAPICH2, MPICH2, openMPI in our cluster)
3) support user defined genomes and operators
4) comprehensive (support elitism, niche, migration, etc.)
5) build-in tree/graph genome and operator (optional. If it doesn't, I will write my own.)
6) C++ (Optional. I am open minded to java or other languages)
7) support multiobjective optimization

Any suggestions about which one best fit these requirements? many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

*Your mileage may vary.*

The fastest one depends on your use case and your implementation. JGap (java, open source) is an established name.

So basically, you're looking for benchmarks? Most (if not all) [published micro-benchmarks are seriously broken](http://www.azulsystems.com/events/javaone_2009/session/2009_J1_Benchmark.pdf) or missing the big names. Macro-benchmarks are usually less broken. I competed with [Drools Planner](http://www.jboss.org/drools/drools-planner) (java, open source, no genetic algorithms, only more recent meta-heuristics such as `simulated annealing`) in [an interesting macro-benchmark](http://www.cs.qub.ac.uk/itc2007/winner/finalorder.htm) where a couple of the competitors used genetic algorithms. So maybe some of their finalist papers are interesting.